# Install python-cmake-buildsystem

Tags: installation, cpython

I followed the install hints here:

https://github.com/davidsansome/python-cmake-buildsystem

And end up in errors while `make`:

```
31%] Built target extension_random
[ 31%] Building C object CMakeBuild/extensions/CMakeFiles/extension_readline.dir/home/sadik/scratch/Python-2.7.3/Modules/readline.c.o
/home/sadik/scratch/Python-2.7.3/Modules/readline.c: In function ‘setup_readline’:
/home/sadik/scratch/Python-2.7.3/Modules/readline.c:889:24: error: ‘Function’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     rl_startup_hook = (Function *)on_startup_hook;
                        ^
/home/sadik/scratch/Python-2.7.3/Modules/readline.c:889:24: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/home/sadik/scratch/Python-2.7.3/Modules/readline.c:889:34: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
     rl_startup_hook = (Function *)on_startup_hook;
                                  ^
/home/sadik/scratch/Python-2.7.3/Modules/readline.c:891:36: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
     rl_pre_input_hook = (Function *)on_pre_input_hook;
                                    ^
/home/sadik/scratch/Python-2.7.3/Modules/readline.c:894:41: error: ‘CPPFunction’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     rl_attempted_completion_function = (CPPFunction *)flex_complete;
                                         ^
/home/sadik/scratch/Python-2.7.3/Modules/readline.c:894:54: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
     rl_attempted_completion_function = (CPPFunction *)flex_complete;
                                                      ^
/home/sadik/scratch/Python-2.7.3/Modules/readline.c: At top level:
/home/sadik/scratch/Python-2.7.3/Modules/readline.c:739:1: warning: ‘on_startup_hook’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 on_startup_hook(void)
 ^
/home/sadik/scratch/Python-2.7.3/Modules/readline.c:746:1: warning: ‘on_pre_input_hook’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 on_pre_input_hook(void)
 ^
/home/sadik/scratch/Python-2.7.3/Modules/readline.c:841:1: warning: ‘flex_complete’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 flex_complete(char *text, int start, int end)
 ^
make[2]: *** [CMakeBuild/extensions/CMakeFiles/extension_readline.dir/home/sadik/scratch/Python-2.7.3/Modules/readline.c.o] Fehler 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeBuild/extensions/CMakeFiles/extension_readline.dir/all] Fehler 2
make: *** [all] Fehler 2
```

There is no way to contact the author so I'm trying it here. Maybe someone had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

@jcfr (myself) is now maintaining python-cmake-buildsystem, more details on this in [python-cmake-buildsystem/issues/6](https://github.com/davidsansome/python-cmake-buildsystem/issues/6)

Problem similar to the one your reported (related to readline) has been fixed by [c0715508](https://github.com/davidsansome/python-cmake-buildsystem/commit/c07155081a87b93efd40a45f7d8564e990963e29). In case the current version doesn't fix the problem. I would suggest you create an issue in the associated github tracker providing more details about the context (version of CMake, compiler, operating system, etc ... )